# Remove all rows where 1 row is 0

Tags: r, statistics

I want to remove a row if a the value in a colume is `0`. I tried that:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 98L, 765L, 13L, 3L, 24L, 24L), Desc = c("hallpo", 
"TEST", "asdfsd", "alla", "asdfs", "sd", "sd"), Val = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 100L, 123L, 2L, 10L), CODEX = c("Random", "Random", "Random", 
"Random", "Random", "Random", "Random"), IsCustomer = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("ID", "Desc", 
"Val", "CODEX", "IsCustomer"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000110788>)
> 
> df$Val[apply(df$Val[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]
Error in df$Val[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any recommendation why my dimension is wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

**Update**

I changed my data.frame and now it is much more complex.

```
df <- dfFile.Value != 0]

Error in `[.data.frame`(df,File.Value != 0) :
```

object File.Value' not found

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   14839 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ test.Person           : Factor w/ 3088 levels "","*asdfasdgw*",..: 9 adf ...
 $ test.Value          : Factor w/ 5484 levels "-243","-8575",..: 3 3 3909 4792 3 1662 3 3 3 3 ...
```

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `apply` on a vector `df$Val`  it should be `apply(df[,-1], 1, ..)`  If you want to remove the 0 rows of Val, `df[Val!=0]`

Comment: I would use `%in%` instead of `==` or `!=` since having NAs in the data will give you unexpected results

Comment: You have a `.` instead of a `[`, I believe. It should be `df <- dfFile[Value != 0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want (data in A):

```
> A
    ID   Desc Val  CODEX IsCustomer
1:   1 hallpo   0 Random       TRUE
2:  98   TEST   0 Random      FALSE
3: 765 asdfsd   0 Random       TRUE
4:  13   alla 100 Random       TRUE
5:   3  asdfs 123 Random      FALSE
6:  24     sd   2 Random      FALSE
```

Try (thank you akrun and David)

```
B <- A[Val != 0]
```

B is now

```
   ID  Desc Val  CODEX IsCustomer
1: 13  alla 100 Random       TRUE
2:  3 asdfs 123 Random      FALSE
3: 24    sd   2 Random      FALSE
4: 24    sd  10 Random       TRUE
```

### Update in response to request in comments

New data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(8964)
Code <- seq_len(15)
Description <- replicate(15, paste(sample(x = letters, size = 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
Value <- sample(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), size = 15, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.55, rep(.05, 9)))
Other <- rep('Stochastic', 15)
Cust <- sample(x = c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 15, replace = TRUE)
Dt <- data.table(Code, Description, Value, Other, Cust)

> Dt
    Code Description Value      Other  Cust
 1:    1       octov     0 Stochastic  TRUE
 2:    2       pwcdl     0 Stochastic  TRUE
 3:    3       ucknw     0 Stochastic  TRUE
 4:    4       mletd     0 Stochastic FALSE
 5:    5       esaej     0 Stochastic  TRUE
 6:    6       jzizz     5 Stochastic FALSE
 7:    7       lcgep     0 Stochastic  TRUE
 8:    8       thrnq     0 Stochastic FALSE
 9:    9       fmdpx     3 Stochastic  TRUE
10:   10       eukwo     0 Stochastic FALSE
11:   11       tuvss     0 Stochastic  TRUE
12:   12       tlqom     0 Stochastic FALSE
13:   13       uirpr     9 Stochastic  TRUE
14:   14       onctx     0 Stochastic FALSE
15:   15       epdgo     0 Stochastic  TRUE

> Dt[Value != 0]
   Code Description Value      Other  Cust
1:    6       jzizz     5 Stochastic FALSE
2:    9       fmdpx     3 Stochastic  TRUE
3:   13       uirpr     9 Stochastic  TRUE
```

Comment: You can tell I'm not a heavy `data.table` user, can you :(. Thank you for the corrections, akrun and David.

Comment: @mrquad That seems to have nothing to do with R, but [Bundler](http://bundler.io/gemfile.htmlhttp://bundler.io/gemfile.html) about which I know absolutely nothing, sorry. The example worked for me. Also, see comment under question about period instead of bracket.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Could you probably rename the columns in your example and show it with different names? Cause I think there is the problem for me...

Comment: @mrquad, answer updated, as requested. Does that help?